# How to determine the sample duration of an NAudio sample?

Tags: naudio

I'm getting audio samples from system sounds using NAudio. Now I'm trying to encode them into a file. However, I need to set the duration for each sample and I don't know how I can calculate that. I need the result in 100 nano seconds (for Media Foundation). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Having access to to the `WaveFormat` object, which is given during a sample event; I could calculate the duration in 100-ns using the following code:

```
private static long BytesToHundredNanoseconds(int bytes, WaveFormat waveFormat)
{
    return 10_000_000L * bytes / waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond;
}
```